# Most Efficent Way to Calculate Areas Serviced Asp.net + SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, geolocation

I am buiilding a webpage that has a database of Companies.

Each company may service areas within a given distance of their depot. 
For example, 1 company may service 200km sourrunding postcode 4214.

I am hoping to get about 1000 companies minimum.

Now the problem I have is I am trying to have a online directory and have a customer search for a company within their postcode.

To avoid the database going through each company, and calulating if the given postcode is within their areas serviced. I have created a table called 
AreasServiced. That just has a ID, Suburb ID, CompanyID

When the company signs up, they say the postcode and the distance they travel. then the webpage calulates all the suburb IDs within the given distance and adds it to the database. Then when a customer searchs for a given postcode it only needs to derive the suburb id and search in the areasserviced database.

The problem I am comming up with, is if I have 1000 customers, this areaserviced table is going to be millions of rows long..

Will that be a problem?

Is there a more efficent way of doing this?

---

in respone to the answer provided:

---

Ive just been implemting a new Geography Table which works fine.

however I just realised..

If every company has a area they service (a postcode that translates into a long/lat) and a distance (eg 200km)

now when the customer searches for companies who service within a area. the database is still going to need go through every single company, calulate the areas they service. and then move on?

Is this the most effective way? or should i stick with a database that has all the areas they service so when a customer searches with a particular postcode i will just query that table for that postcode?

---

I may have solved it :

```
   declare @p geography;
   set @p = (select coordinates from geolookup where geoid = 3714);

   select * from Depots 
   join geolookup on geolookup.geoid = depots.suburbID
   where geolookup.coordinates.STDistance(@p)<= depots.DistanceTravelled
```

Answer (score 1):

Just save the geographical coordinates of the center of the circle that the company covers in a geography data type.

You can then efficiently query for all near by service locations by passing a single lat long using STWithin in your WHERE  clause.

[Selecting geographical points within area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550445/selecting-geographical-points-within-area)

This way you will have a single record per company and you won't have to calculate and insert all the suberbs a company covers.

Comment: thanks. i was really holding off on changing my database to the geographical data type (i only found about it recently)
but you have now given me a good enough reason to make the change :)

cheers!