# How do i select objects within a geographic regions in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation, selection, geopandas

I'm trying to selection objects within a region from a pandas dataframe which contains a list of item ids and lat lon pairs. Is there a selection method for this?
I think this would be similar to this SO question but using PANDAS instead of SQL

[Selecting geographical points within area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550445/selecting-geographical-points-within-area)

Here is my table saved in *locations.csv*

```
ID, LAT, LON
001,35.00,-75.00
002,35.01,-80.00 
...
999,25.76,-64.00
```

I can load the dataframe, and select a rectangular region:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('locations.csv', delimiter=',')
lat_max = 32.323496
lat_min = 25.712767
lon_max = -72.863358
lon_min = -74.729456
small_df = df[df['LAT'] > lat_min][df['LAT'] < lat_max][df['LON'] < lon_max][df['LON'] > lon_min]
```

How would I select objects within an irregular region?

How would I structure the dataframe selection command?

I can build a lambda function that will produce a True value for LAT and LON within the region but I'm not sure how to use that with a pandas dataframe.

Comment: You are only ever going to be able to do selections within a rectangle with simple `df.LAT.between() & df.LON.between()`. Of course you can make abitrary regions by joining together many smaller rectangles, but that's difficult. More complicated selection for a point within an arbitrary geometry is going to require something like `geopandas` and libraries like `Shapely` which allow for spatial analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A process to select points within a region as performed by the working code below starts with creating 2 geodataframes. The first one contains a polygon, and the second contains all the points to do `spatial join` with the first. The spatial join operator `within` is used to enable the points that fall inside the polygon to be selected. The result of the operation is also a geodataframe, it contains only the required points that fall within the area of the polygon.

The content of `locations.csv`; 6 lines with column headers.
Note: no spaces in the first row.

```
ID,LAT,LON
1, 15.1, 10.0
2, 15.2, 15.1
3, 15.3, 20.2
4, 15.4, 25.3
5, 15.5, 30.4
```

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkt
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
from shapely.wkt import loads

# Create a geo-dataframe `polygon_df` having 1 row of polygon
# This polygon will be used to select points in a geodataframe
d = {'poly_id':[1], 'wkt':['POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))']}
df = pd.DataFrame( data=d )
geometry = [loads(pgon) for pgon in df.wkt]
polygon_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, \
                   crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'}, \
                   geometry=geometry)

# One can plot this polygon with the command:
# polygon_df.plot()

# Read the file with `pandas`
locs = pd.read_csv('locations.csv', sep=',')

# Making it a geo-dataframe with new name: `geo_locs`
geo_locs = gpd.GeoDataFrame(locs, crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'})
locs_geom = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(geo_locs.LON, geo_locs.LAT)]
geo_locs['wkt'] = geo_locs.apply( lambda x: Point(x.LON, x.LAT), axis=1 )
geo_locs = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geo_locs, crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'}, \
    geometry=geo_locs['wkt'])

# Do a spatial join of `point` within `polygon`, get the result in `pts_in_poly` GeodataFrame.
pts_in_poly = gpd.sjoin(geo_locs, polygon_df, op='within', how='inner')

# Print the ID of the points that fall within the polygon.
print(pts_in_poly.ID)

# The output will be:
#2    3
#3    4
#4    5
#Name: ID, dtype: int64

# Plot the polygon and all the points.
ax1 = polygon_df.plot(color='lightgray', zorder=1)
geo_locs.plot(ax=ax1, zorder=5, color="red")
```

The output plot:

[image]

In the plot, the points with ID's 3, 4, and 5 fall within the polygon.

Comment: And if you add this line of code: `pts_in_poly.plot(ax=ax1, zorder=6, color='green')`, the points inside the region will be plotted on top in green color.